# htaccess custom url listing using mod_rewrite

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have used .htaccess to successfully mask urls with custom, clean urls in the style of subdirectories for the top level of a domain:

### normal .htaccess config (works)

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ /index.php?page=$1&subject=$2 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ /index.php?page=$1 [QSA]
```

gives me:

> /page/subject
>
> /page

Now, in using specific deployments for different PHP files, I would like to make subset directories for said deployments as in:

### desired additional config (not working - throws 500 errors)

```
RewriteRule ^mobile/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ /mobile.php?page=$1&subject=$2 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^mobile/([^/]+)$ /mobile.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]
```

to give me:

> /mobile/page/subject
>
> /mobile/page

I've tried changing [QSA,L] to [NC,L] and nothing. Any ideas? Any help is greatly appreciated! :) Thank you in advance.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `RewriteRule ^([^/]+)mobile/....`?

Comment: not doing it for me... i am following the logic of another rewrite hack i did to serve up images: `RewriteRule ^images/([^/]+)/(.*)\.(jpg|png|jpeg|gif)$ /images/index.php?image=$2&res=$1&ext=$3 [NC,L] `

Answer (score 0):

This rule cause endless looping:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ /index.php?page=$1 [QSA]
```

You need to add before him some limitation RewriteCond.
Here yours rewrite call stack:

[image]

P.S.
NEVER MIND, i forgot created **mobile.php**, and I gote rewrite loop, Sorry for that.

Comment: it's there: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]` and that already works... thanks, tho!

Comment: Nope.This RewriteCond for RewriteRule ^ - [L] ONLY.

Comment: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ /index.php?page=$1&subject=$2 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ /index.php?page=$1 [QSA, L]` this works...i am looking for an answer for a different kind of instance of this with a base-name, like 'mobile'

Comment: please notice the 'L' in the the comment above... still not working for instances of 'mobile' and works fine for top level... would be nice if i can get a definitive solution.

Comment: 'L' means nothing here, because it`s internal redirect to the SAME server, to the same htaccess, it will continue until no one RewriteRule doesn't much. I update my original answer - look in rewrite call stack - and you will see that problem in this rule.

Comment: ok, this set of code performs two functions: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ /index.php?page=$1 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ /index.php?page=$1&section=$2 [QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^images/([^/]+)/(.*)\.(jpg|png|jpeg|gif)$ /images/index.php?image=$2&res=$1&ext=$3 [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]` as i need... how to add an additional layer for 'mobile' ... any definitive solution? :)

Comment: i don't need a general indication of error. i need an answer... :)

Comment: In general yours solution is right, but, as I say you before, you just need to add some RewriteCond to stop endless looping. Simple add `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f` before `RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ /index.php?page=$1 [QSA]`.

Comment: Forgive my curiosity, what program is that in the screenshot? Looks like a handy way to debug .htaccess

Comment: This is a private program used within our web dev company. Its based on original apache server, not just emulator, but full apache stack program with in http request, so it`s pretty accurate.

Comment: a magician never reveals secrets ... still waiting for that magical answer! ;)